# linq to entities select distinct in

Tags: linq-to-entities, distinct

I have struggled a little in getting my head around the LINQ to entities nomenclature. And would very much appreciate some help working out how to use the LINQ nomenclature effectively and efficiently (that is having the database return the smallest number of records rather than iterate through a larger collection at a programmatic level). Up until now I have often relied on stored procedures and views to do the work, but would appreciate some help learning the LINQ way.

To begin, would someone help 'translate' the SQL query:

```
SELECT     InfusionDrugID, fullname
FROM         dbo.infusionDrugs
WHERE     (InfusionDrugID IN
                      (SELECT DISTINCT infusionDrugID
                        FROM dbo.fixedTimeDilutions))
```

I would also be interested in how to select records NOT IN another table.

this is made a little more complex in that fixedTimeDilutions uses table per concrete type inheritance, and inherits from the abstract class infusionDilutions, thus the linq statement will have to include a line such as.

```
from inf in PICUentities.infusionDilutions.OfType<fixedTimeDilutions>()
```

Thank you for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with linq you have to *think* linq. That is, try to express whatever you want to achieve in terms of C# code with linq and "forget" SQL.

However, if you do that you'll quickly find out that it is impossible to forget SQL, because many combinations of linq and other C# code just don't translate into SQL. So it's give and take, think linq, but get to know what Entity Framework does and doesn't swallow.

In your case, you want `infusionDrugs` that are found in `fixedTimeDilutions`. The linq way would be:

```cs
c.infusionDrugs
    .Where(i => c.fixedTimeDilutions.OfType<fixedTimeDilutions>().Select(f => f.infusionDrugID).Distinct())
    .Contains(i.InfusionDrugID)) // Or i.InfusionDrugID.Value
```

(where `c` is your context)

Or

```cs
c.infusionDrugs
    .Where(i => c.fixedTimeDilutions.OfType<fixedTimeDilutions>()
        .Any(f => f.infusionDrugID == i.InfusionDrugID)) // Or i.InfusionDrugID.Value
```

(forgive me if I forgot some bracket)

Comment: Thank you - works beautifully - i'll start trying to 'think linq'